# "das neue" oder "das Neue"?

Tags: spelling, capitalization, nominalization

Ich korrigiere gerade die Abschlussarbeit eines Freundes und bin mir bei einer Stelle unsicher:

> Da in einem zukünftigen Labor sowohl die alte 3-Lagen-Schwenkvorrichtung als auch die Neue parallel betrieben werden sollen, muss volle Abwärtskompatibilität der Software gewährleistet sein.

Muss "die Neue" groß oder klein sein? Und vor allem: Warum?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In diesem Fall ist es  **kleinzuschreiben**. Das Adjektiv bezieht sich auf "3-Lagen-Schwenkvorrichtung" wie "alte". Du kannst das überprüfen, indem du das Hauptwort ergänzt:

> Da in einem zukünftigen Labor sowohl die alte 3-Lagen-Schwenkvorrichtung als auch *die neue 3-Lagen-Schwenkvorrichtung* parallel betrieben werden sollen, muss volle Abwärtskompatibilität der Software gewährleistet sein.

Was passiert, wenn die Regel nicht beachtet wird, ist aus folgendem Beispiel ersichtlich:

Männerrezension bei Amazon:

> "Der Versand der Waschmaschine war gewohnt schnell und meine Alte wurde auch gleich mitgenommen."

---

Es gibt allerdings einige Fälle, in denen Adjektive substantiviert verwenden werden und somit **großgeschrieben** werden:

- wenn ein bestimmter Artikel davorsteht und es als eigenständiges Substantiv verwendet wird:

  > das Neueste, das Gute
- wenn ein unbestimmter Artikel davorsteht:

  > ein Rot / Grün / Blau, ein Dummer
- wenn der bestimmte oder unbestimmte Artikel

  > Sie erzählten Amüsantes und Peinliches.
  >   Es ist ein Spiel für Große und Kleine.
- wenn eine Präposition davorsteht.

  > im Dunklen, ins Schwarze, im Warmen, zum Besten geben;
  >   auf Englisch, auf dem Laufenden bleiben;
  >   im Allgemeinen, von Nahem / Weitem.
- wenn ein Pronomen davorsteht:

  > meine Kleinste, dieser Große, seine Alte
- wenn ein unbestimmtes Zahlwort davorsteht:

  > alles Gute, viel Schönes, nichts Besonderes, manches Böse
- Nichtdeklinierte Adjektive in Paarformeln zur Bezeichnung von Personen werden großgeschrieben:

  > Jung und Alt, Arm und Reich, *Gleich und Gleich gesellt sich gern.*
- wenn sie von Orts- oder Ländernamen auf *-er* abgeleitet sind:

  > das Wiener Würstchen, die Berliner Luft, der Schweizer Käse

Comment: Merci! Habe intuitiv auch auf klein getippt, aber konnte es nicht begründen... danke für die umfassende Antwort! :)

Answer (score 7):

Mein Bauchgefühl sagt mir, es sollte kleingeschrieben werden. Ich würde es umformulieren:

> Da in einem zukünftigen Labor sowohl die alte als auch die neue 3-Lagen-Schwenkvorrichtung parallel betrieben werden sollen, muss volle Abwärtskompatibilität der Software gewährleistet sein.

Ich würde "Neue" großschreiben, wenn aus dem Satz oder Kontext kein anderes Substantiv hervorgeht, das von "Neue" beschrieben wird. Aber wie gesagt, das ist alles nur Bauchgefühl.

Comment: Sehe ich auch so. Ist das nicht ganz klassische Substantivierung?

Comment: "die Neue" ist eine 6-Lagen-Schwenkvorrichtung, deshalb funktioniert das nicht ganz so einfach... aber hätte auch auf neue klein getippt. Ich weiß halt nur, dass es bei der Substantivierung früher mal Ausnahmen gab, die dann mal geändert wurden... und dann war ich so verwirrt, dass ich die Regeln vergessen hab. ^^

Comment: Hm, in dem Fall kannst Du versuchen, auf die Gemeinsamkeit zu reduzieren, also z.B. *sowohl die alte als auch die neue Schwenkvorrichtung*...

Comment: Stimmt ganz genau. Ohne "Bauch" steht hier die Regel dazu: [Duden 73](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibregeln/gross-und-kleinschreibung#K73)

Comment: oder "... sowohl die alte 3-Lagen- als auch die neue 6-Lagen-Schwenkvorrichtung ..."