# Wann schreibe ich ein Adjektiv groß?

Tags: grammar, adjective, spelling

Bei uns im Büro kam gerade die hitzige Diskussion auf, wann Adjektive großgeschrieben werden.
Unser Beispiel war "Reich' mir mal bitte das Buch!" "Welches Buch?" "**Das (d/D)icke …**"

Wird in diesem Fall das D groß- oder kleingeschrieben? Und welche Regel greift da? Wir sind uns ein wenig uneinig und haben jeweils einige Beispiele für unsere Behauptungen.

Comment: Her mit den Beispielen!

Comment: "Beispiele" war vielleicht das falsche Wort. Argumente für unsere jeweiligen Positionen passt eher. Aber die finden sich mittleweile alle hier in den Antworten wieder, also wäre es redundant, sie hier alle nochmal aufzuzählen...

Comment: Related: [When should one capitalize adjectives/numerals which are used as noun?](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3401/when-should-one-capitalize-adjectives-numerals-which-are-used-as-noun)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Adjektive werden großgeschrieben, wenn diese als Substantive (Nomen) gebraucht werden.

Hier noch ein paar Beispiele zur Großschreibung:

> Heute gehen die **Alten** zur Kirche.
>
> Der **Älteste** heiratet bald.
>
> Sie ist wirklich die **Schönste**.

Bezieht sich das Adjektiv auf ein vorheriges/nachstehendes Substantiv, dann wird dieses kleingeschrieben.

Hier Beispiele:

> Heute gehen die **alten Männer** zur Kirche.
>
> Der **älteste Sohn** heiratet bald.
>
> Sie ist wirklich die **schönste Tänzerin**.

Das gilt auch, wenn das Substantiv im Satz davor steht. Zum Beispiel:

> Mir gefallen alle Krawatten sehr gut. Besonders mag ich die
>   **gestreiften** und die **gepunkteten**.

In deinem Beispiel würde man also schreiben "Das dicke" – das Adjektiv "dicke" bezieht sich auf das Substantiv "Buch" aus dem vorigen Satz. Es wird also als Beifügung (Attribut) gebraucht, und nicht als Substantiv.

Quellen und weitere Informationen:

[Verzeichnis:Deutsch/Rechtschreibung/Groß- und Kleinschreibung von Adjektiven](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Verzeichnis:Deutsch/Rechtschreibung/Gro%C3%9F-_und_Kleinschreibung_von_Adjektiven#Substantivierte_Adjektive)

[Duden - Groß und Kleinschreibung](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/Gro%C3%9F-%20und%20Kleinschreibung)

Comment: Zu »Adjektive werden groß geschrieben, wenn diese Als Substantive (Nomen) gebraucht werden.« sollte man hinzufügen, dass diese Nomen dann aber keine Adjektive mehr sind, sondern eben Nomen. Substantive schreibt man nur am Beginn eines Satzes groß.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Der letzte Satz widerspricht sich selbst :)

Comment: Sorry, das erste Wort im letzten Satz sollte natürlich "Adjektive" (nicht "Substantive") heißen. Leider kann ich es jetzt nicht mehr korrigieren.

Comment: Vielen Dank für die ausführliche Antwort (und dass du mir mit meiner Vermutung zustimmst...hihi). :)

Answer (score 6):

Im Deutschen werden i. d. R. neben dem „Satzanfang“ nur die **Kerne von Nominalphrasen** (NP) großgeschrieben. Das ist eine syntaktische oder grammatische Wortart oder Rolle, die überwiegend als notwendige Ergänzung von Verben (vgl. Rektion) vorkommt (vulgo Subjekt und Objekte). Es gibt eine lexikalische Wortart, nämlich die **Substantive**, die syntaktisch praktisch nur diese Rolle einnehmen können; aber auch die meisten anderen Wortarten, insbesondere Verben und Adjektive, können so verwendet werden. **Pronomen** als Kern einer NP werden fast immer kleingeschrieben, weil sie die vollständige Phrase bilden (was sonst nur Eigennamen und Stoffsubstantive ‘mass nouns’ sowie Pluralsubstantive in dieser Funktion können) und keine Linksattribute (z. B. Adjektive, Artikel und andere Pronomen) unterstützen.

Der Kern einer NP bestimmt das Genus der gesamten NP, ohne es üblicherweise selbst anzuzeigen: Substantive und substantivische Derivationsmorpheme haben ein inhärentes Genus. Der Kern kann den Kasus, der i. d. R. vom Verb bestimmt wird und die syntaktische Rolle der NP bestimmt, oft selbst anzeigen und alle Begleiter müssen damit kongruieren. Dies gilt auch für zusammengesetzte Nominalphrasen, während der Numerus nur in einer Teil-NP kongruent sein muss (z. B. *Ich kenne den Hof und die Häuser*).

Besondere Berücksichtigung verlangen die Possessivbegleiter einer NP. Possessivpronomen werden kleingeschrieben (wie auch Demonstrativpronomen, die man zu den Artikelwörtern zählen kann). Eigennamen werden weiterhin großgeschrieben und stehen im Genitiv, während dieser Kasus heute praktisch nicht mehr für allgemeine Substantive als Possessivum verwendet wird und die wenigen Verben, die (schrift- und hochsprachlich) noch eine Genitivergänzung unterstützen, dies bevorzugt für Pronomen und sonst keinesfalls ohne Artikel tun (z. B. *wir gedenken *Claudias / ?der Claudia / ihrer / des Unglücks*).

### Konstruierte Beispiele

#### Einstellige Nominalphrasen

- *Ich mag dich.* – Personalpronomen
- *Ich mag Sie.* – Personalpronomen in Höflichkeitsform
- *Ich mag niemand(en).* – Personalpronomen?
- *Ich mag Claudia.* – Eigenname
- *Ich mag Wasser.* – Stoffsubstantiv
- *Ich mag Häuser.* – Substantiv im Plural ohne unbestimmten Artikel

#### Einfache zweistellige Nominalphrasen

- *Ich mag kaltes Wasser.* – Stoffsubstantiv mit adjektivischem Attribut
- *Ich mag kalte Wasser.* – Substantiv im Plural mit adjektivischem Attribut
- *Ich mag einige Häuser.* – Substantiv im Plural mit quasi-unbestimmten Artikel
- *Ich mag die Häuser.* – Substantiv im Plural mit bestimmten Artikel (mglw. Demonstrativpronomen)
- *Ich mag ein Haus.* – Substantiv mit unbestimmtem Artikel
- *Ich mag das Haus.* – Substantiv mit bestimmtem Artikel
- *Ich mag dieses Haus.* – Substantiv mit Demonstrativpronomen
- *Ich mag dein Haus.* – Substantiv mit Possessivpronomen

#### Mehrstellige Nominalphrasen mit Prädikatsattribut

- *Ich mag ein rotes Haus.* – Substantiv mit schwachem, unbestimmten Artikel und adjektivischem Attribut
- *Ich mag das rote Haus.* – Substantiv mit starkem, bestimmten Artikel und adjektivischem Attribut
- *Ich mag dein rotes Haus.* – Substantiv mit schwachem Possessivpronomen und adjektivischem Attribut
- *Ich mag dieses rote Haus.* – Substantiv mit starkem Demonstrativpronomen und adjektivischem Attribut

#### Mehrstellige Nominalphrasen mit Possessivattribut

- *Ich mag dein Haus.* – Substantiv mit Possessivpronomen
- *Ich mag Claudias Haus.* – Substantiv mit Eigennamen im Genitiv als Possessivum
- *Ich mag des Königs Haus.* – Substantiv mit Genitiv-NP als Possessivum
- *Ich mag das Haus von Claudia.* – Substantiv mit Artikel und Rechtsattribut mit Eigennamen als Possessivum
- *Ich mag das Haus des Königs.* – Substantiv mit Artikel und Rechtsattribut mit Genitivsubstantiv als Possessivum

#### Mehrstellige Nominalphrasen mit komplexem Kern

- *Ich mag das Haus und den Hof.* – Substantive mit Artikeln und Konjunktion
- *Ich mag das Rote Rathaus.* – Adjektiv im Eigenname mit Artikel

#### Nominalphrasen mit Substantivierungen

- *Ich mag Grün.* – **Substantiviertes Adjektiv** ohne Artikel
- *Ich mag die Grünen.* – **Substantiviertes Adjektiv** mit Artikel
- *Ich mag das Leiden.* – Substantiviertes Verb mit Artikel
- *Ich mag dein Ich (im Freud’schen Sinne).* – substantiviertes Pronomen mit Possessivpronomen (und Rechtsattribut)

### Beispiel aus der Frage (TL;DR)

Wenn wie im Beispiel kein schulgrammatischer, schriftsprachlicher Satz vorliegt, ist es etwas komplizierter, die Nominalphrase zu bestimmen, weil sie auseinandergerissen ist, was in der oralen Grammatik völlig normal ist, aber immer noch selten in Grammatikbüchern beschrieben oder im Unterricht gelehrt wird. Häufig wird hierfür mit Ellipsen argumentiert, die den unnötigen Beigeschmack haben, dass dort etwas Essenzielles fehlen würde, was eben gerade nicht der Fall ist.

Man kann darüber diskutieren, ob die verblose Nachfrage mit Interrogativpronomen Bestandteil der NP ist, ganz sicher ist es die ebenfalls verblose Antwort.

- *„Reich mir mal bitte **das Buch**!“ „Welches Buch?“ „**Das dicke**.“*
- *„Reich mir mal bitte **das dicke Buch**!“* – Linksattribut
- *„Reich mir mal bitte **das Buch, das dicke**!“* – Rechtsattribut
- *„Reich mir mal bitte **das dicke**!“ „Welches dicke?“ „**Das Buch.**“*
- *„Reich mir mal bitte **das dicke, das Buch**!“*
- *„Reich mir mal bitte **das Dicke**!“ „Welches Dicke?“ „Die Bibel.“* – „Eigenname“
- *„Reich mir mal bitte **den Diercke**!“* – Eigenname

Im ersten und vierten Listenpunkt sieht man übrigens auch, warum ich oben „Satzanfang“ in Anführungszeichen gesetzt habe, denn großgeschrieben wird das erste Wort jedes orthographischen Satzes, während grammatisch der Satz oft mit der Verbalphrase gleichgesetzt wird, die hier aus finitem Verb *reich+* plus notwendige Objekte (Dativergänzung *mir* und Akkusativergänzung *… Buch …* etc.) und optionale, hier partikelartige Adverbiale *mal bitte* besteht sowie (weil Imperativ) ohne Nominativsubjekt auskommt.

Answer (score 1):

Die Beispiele für die Großschreibung würden mich interessieren. Das aktuelle Beispiel ist jedenfalls keins, dem ich die Großschreibung zuschreiben kann. Adjektive werden nicht großgeschrieben, es sei denn, sie sind Teil eines Eigennamens. Sei also "Das Große Buch" ein anerkanntes Synonym für die Bibel (was es nicht ist), dann wäre das in Ordnung, ansonsten niemals!

Edit: Es sei denn, wir reden von substantivierten Adjektiven, aber ich glaube, der Fall ist klar, oder? In dem Fall sind es ja genau genommen keine Adjektive mehr (z. B. "das Schöne auf der Welt").

Comment: vollkommen richtig. Substantivierte Adjektive sind keine Adjektive. Es sind Substantive (die zufällig eben von Adjektiven abgeleitet wurden). Es gibt ja auch Substantive, die von Verben abgeleitet sind (»Hier ist Fußballspielen verboten.«). Das sind dann auch keine Verben, sondern eben Substantive.