# Ordinalzahl nach Artikeln

Tags: capitalization, numbers

Ich würde gerne wissen, ob in den nachfolgenden Sätzen die Ordinalzahlen *erste, zweite* und *dritte* groß- oder kleingeschrieben werden:

> Das Tripel besteht aus drei Wortgruppen. Die Erste ist für X, die Zweite für Y und die Dritte für Z.
>
> Das Tripel besteht aus drei Wortgruppen. Die erste ist für X, die zweite für Y und die dritte für Z.

Ich tendiere dazu, sie großzuschreiben.

Allerdings habe ich in einem Forum die Aussage (ohne Quellenangabe) gelesen, dass ich die Ordinalzahlen kleinschreiben muss, da ich das Wort (*Wortgruppen* in meinem Fall), auf das sich die Nummerierung bezieht, im Satz davor nenne. Leider kann ich in meinem Grammatikduden keine passende Aussage finden.

Welche Schreibweise ist korrekt?

Comment: Related: [When should one capitalize adjectives/numerals which are used as noun?](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3401/when-should-one-capitalize-adjectives-numerals-which-are-used-as-noun)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Die Frage ist berechtigt, denn grundsätzlich werden Zahladjektive kleingeschrieben, während man die substantivierten Ordnungszahlwörter großschreibt. In diesem Fall gilt der folgende Paragraf der amtlichen Regeln für die deutsche Rechtschreibung:

> **§ 58**
>
> In folgenden Fällen schreibt man Adjektive, Partizipien und Pronomen
>   klein, obwohl sie formale Merkmale der Substantivierung aufweisen.
>
> (1) Adjektive, Partizipien und Pronomen, die sich auf ein vorhergehendes
>   oder nachstehendes Substantiv beziehen, zum Beispiel:
>
> (…)
>
> *Zwei Männer betraten den Raum; der erste trug einen Anzug, der zweite Jeans und
>   Pullover.*
>
> (…)

Die entsprechende Rechtschreibregel im *Duden* lautet:

> **Regel 73**
>
> Adjektive und Partizipien mit Artikel werden kleingeschrieben, wenn sie Beifügung (Attribut) zu einem vorangehenden oder folgenden Substantiv sind.

Comment: Was zitierst Du da?

Comment: @Robert: Das sind die amtlichen Regeln der deutschen Rechtschreibung. Man findet sie gewöhnlich in einem Anhang im Duden Band 1 _Die deutsche Rechtschreibung_ oder auch [hier](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf).

Comment: … oder [hier](http://www.duden.de/sites/default/files/downloads/amtliche_Regelungen.pdf).

Comment: oder [hier](http://canoo.net/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/index.html) als online HTML-Version.

Answer (score 2):

Meiner Meinung nach sollten die Zahlwörter kleingeschrieben werden, da man so ergänzen könnte:

… Die **erste Gruppe** ist für …

Dann ist die Kleinschreibung klar. Auch wenn man „Gruppe“ wegen Redundanz weglässt, was natürlich sinnvoll ist, bleibt die Kleinschreibung erhalten.

Comment: Man könnte auch so ergänzen: "der Dicke" -> "der dicke Mann", trotzdem schreibt man im ersten Fall "Dicke" groß.

Comment: @ karoshi: Das kannst du so nicht sagen. So wie du es schreibst, ist "der Dicke" ein alleinstehendes Substantiv. In citronas'  Beispiel geht es aber explizit darum, dass "die Wortgruppe" (oder in deinem Fall "der Mann" ) zuvor schon genannt wurde. Dann ist "dicke" nur ein Adjektiv und wird klein geschrieben.

Comment: @dervonnebenaan Genau!