# "das rote [Haus]" — Großschreibung, wenn Nomen ausgelassen

Tags: spelling, capitalization, ellipsis

Man stelle sich folgendes Gespräch vor:

> Person A: Siehst du das Haus da drüben?
>
> Person B: Welches Haus meinst du? Meinst du etwa *das **r**ote*?

Frage: Ist die letzte Frage von Person B bezüglich der Groß- und Kleinschreibung korrekt? Oder müsste es richtig *das **R**ote* heißen?

Comment: Related: [Ordinalzahl nach Artikeln](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/17392/9551)

Answer (score 6):

Zunächst sollte man mal festhalten, dass der Duden kein offizielles Nachschlagewerk der deutschen Sprache ist, sondern dass im Zweifelsfall die [Empfehlungen des Rats für deutsche Rechtschreibung](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf) zu konsultieren sind.

Auf Seite 53 des verlinkten Dokuments beginnt der Abschnitt D, der die Groß- und Kleinschreibung behandelt. Dort steht gleich zu Beginn in D 0 (2):

> Die Großschreibung wird im Deutschen verwendet zur Kennzeichnung von [...] Substantiven und Substantivierungen

Falls es sich bei »das rote/Rote« um eine Substantivierung handelt, ist es daher großzuschreiben.

Kapitel 2.2 beschäftigt sich dann in Detail mit Substantivierungen:

> **§ 57**
>   **Wörter anderer Wortarten schreibt man groß, wenn sie als Substantive gebraucht werden (= Substantivierungen).**
>
> Substantivierte Wörter nehmen die Eigenschaften von Substantiven an (vgl. § 55). Man erkennt sie im Text an zumindest einem der folgenden Merkmale:
>   a) an einem vorausgehenden Artikel (der, die, das; ein, eine, ein) [...]

§ 55 lautet übrigens: »Substantive schreibt man groß.«

Im Beispiel geht dem Wort »rote/Rote« der Artikel »das« voraus. Das ist also ein deutliches Indiz für eine Substantivierung. Demnach wäre hier eine Großschreibung angebracht.

Dann folgt aber der § 58:

> **§ 58**
>   **In folgenden Fällen schreibt man Adjektive, Partizipien und Pronomen klein, obwohl sie formale Merkmale der Substantivierung aufweisen.**
>
> (1) Adjektive, Partizipien und Pronomen, die sich auf ein vorhergehendes oder nachstehendes Substantiv beziehen, zum Beispiel:
>
> 1. Sie war die aufmerksamste und klügste meiner Zuhörerinnen.
> 2. Vor dem Haus spielten viele Kinder, einige kleine im Sandkasten, die größeren am Klettergerüst.
> 3. Es waren neun Teilnehmer erschienen, auf den zehnten wartete man vergebens.
> 4. Alte Schuhe sind meist bequemer als neue.
> 5. Dünne Bücher lese ich in der Freizeit, dicke im Urlaub.
> 6. Zwei Männer betraten den Raum; der erste trug einen Anzug, der zweite Jeans und Pullover.
> 7. Leih mir bitte deine Farbstifte, ich habe meine/die meinen/die meinigen vergessen.
> 8. Der Verkäufer zeigte mir seine Auswahl an Krawatten. Die gestreiften und gepunkteten gefielen mir am besten.

(Im Original sind die Beispiele nicht durchnummeriert, ich hielt es aber für eine gute Idee, sie hier auf diese Weise darzustellen.)

In den Beispielen 1 bis 7 steht das Substantiv, auf welches sich das fragliche Adjektiv, Partizip oder Pronomen bezieht, immer im selben Satz, so dass man eventuell meinen könnte, dass das möglicherweise eine Voraussetzung wäre damit diese Regel gilt.

Aber das Beispiel Nr. 8 macht klar, dass das nicht so ist: Hier verweisen die Wörter »gestreiften« und »gepunkteten« auf ein Substantiv (nämlich »Krawatten«) welches nicht im selben Satz steht, sondern davor.

Weil in

> Welches Haus meinst du? Meinst du etwa das rote?

genau dieselbe Konstellation vorliegt, kommt hier also der § 58 zur Anwendung, welchen den § 57 übertrumpft.

Das Wort ist also tatsächlich klein zu schreiben.

---

**Nachtrag zum Duden als Nicht-mehr-Standardwerk**

Den Status ein offizielles Nachschlagewerk der deutschen Sprache zu sein hat der Duden 1996 mit Inkrafttreten der Rechtschreibreform verloren. Auch davor war er nicht im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum verbindlich gültig, sondern nur in Deutschland, nicht jedoch z.B. in Österreich.

Seit 1996 gibt der Rat für deutsche Rechtschreibung Empfehlungen heraus, und die Unterrichts- oder Kultus-Ministerien aller deutschsprachigen Länder haben entschieden, ihre Lehrpläne nach diesen Empfehlungen auszurichten, und auch beim Verfassen neuer amtlicher Dokumente hat man in diesen Ländern beschlossen, diesen Empfehlungen zu folgen.

Für Schüler und Beamte sind diese Empfehlungen also verbindliche Regeln. Wer kein Schüler und kein Beamter ist, darf frei entscheiden, ob er diesen Empfehlungen folgen möchte oder nicht.

Answer (score -1):

Duden:

> Regel 73
>
> Adjektive und Partizipien mit Artikel werden kleingeschrieben, wenn sie Beifügung (Attribut) zu einem vorangehenden oder folgenden Substantiv sind.

Comment: Und, ist das hier der Fall?

Comment: Wenn du, wie du glaubst, die Antwort ohnehin schon kennst, warum fragst du dann?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, es ist auf SE durchaus üblich, eigene Fragen zu beantworten, wenn man nach Recherche meint, eine Antwort gefunden zu haben.