# Kardinalzahl als ein substantiviertes Adjektiv?

Tags: adjective, capitalization, numbers, nominalization

> **This question also has an answer here (in German):**
>   *http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17392*

I would like to say in German the following:

> The first chart describes ..., the second one shows... .

My version:

> Die erste Grafik beschreibt ..., die zweite zeigt ... .

I am not sure whether I should use *die zweite* or rather *die Zweite* (i.e. treat *zweite* as a “substantiviertes Adjektiv”).

Comment: *…die zweite…* is correct. *Die Zweite* would introduce a new unrelated subject into the sentence, which isn't meant here.

Comment: @Hulk and other close voters: Please note [this Meta discussion](//german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/807/2594).

Comment: _Die zweite_ can be seen as a short form for _Die zweite Grafik_, therefore ist must be _zweite_, not _Zweite_. This has been discussed before in the answers to the linked question, and I cannot see that this question adds anything new.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft close vote retracted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short run-down of the linked answer that was in German:

Substantiated numerals are generally - like Substantives - written in upper-case.

> Der Erste der diesjährigen Weltrangliste schafft die Strecke in etwa 5,9s.

but with an exception: In case there is another substantive around that the numerals relate to, they are written in lower case even if they have all the traits as before:

> Die 100m-Läufer starten heute um 10:00 Uhr; der erste wird wahrscheinlich in unter 6s ins Ziel kommen.

So in your case, there actually is a related substantive, *Grafik*, so your proposal for writing the numeral in lower case is correct.

Comment: An example from German literature: _Wie nun der erste Bediente mit einer Schüssel schönem Essen kam, stieß der Bauer seine Frau an und sagte „Grethe, das war der erste,“ und meinte es wäre derjenige, welcher das erste Essen brächte._ (Brüder Grimm: Doctor Allwissend)